# Telerik grid posted values making Modelstate invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, data-annotations, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

We are in process of upgrading from Telerik Q3 2010 asp.net mvc extensions to Q1 2011. Previously, in grid editing disabled values were not posted in the form but now they are posted as null values. I asked the Telerik team and they confirmed that this is expected behavior and they will be posting all the model back to controller.

What is bothering me is that a null value for a field is making Modelstate invalid even though the field is nullable and I'm not decorating it with Required attribute.

Here is my view model:

```
public class VMDoctorHospital
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int DrHospitalID { get; set; }
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int DoctorID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Personal Clinic?")]
        public bool PersonalClinic { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Clinic Name")]
        public string ClinicName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Hospital"), UIHint("IntStrEditor")]
        public int? HospitalID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Doctor's Position")]
//ohter fields
}
```

in the Model PersonalClinic flag dictates which input (Clinic name or HospitalID) will be disabled and hidden.

[image]

[image]

Now, even if they are posting null value for HospitalID when personalClinin checkbox is checked, it perfectly makes sense and on controller side HospitalID should be accepting null value as it is nullable and not REQUIRED but in reality I receive "The value "null" is not valid for HospitalID" in ModelstateDictionary.

I have no idea what is making it behave in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This was considered a bug and will be addressed with the upcoming release.

Comment: at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/grid-editing-problem-telerik-q1-2011-beta.aspx you described that sending the whole model is an expected behavior. would u describe a little bit what is bug here: sending whole model or modelstate being false when it should be true?

Comment: There was a cases where the string "null" was posted for integer fields which is what the bug is. Did you try upgrading? Did the problem went away? If not please open a new forum thread and send us a sample project.

Comment: the problem with sample project was posted on telerik forums by Mr. Tassadaque Zia at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/beta/modelstate-isvalid-is-false-for-optional-fields-in-grid.aspx.  i m talking about same problem but beta forums seem to have been moved or inaccessible. Let me know if u need another copy of sample project containing the bug

Comment: I am asking you again - did you try upgrading to the latest official version? As I already explained we fixed a similar problem AFTER the beta. If the problem is not fixed after the upgrade - open a NEW forum thread and send us a sample project. The problem in the aforementioned thread is resolved in the latest version.

Comment: no i have not. did not know it was released. will update you in a day or two. thanks for quick reply